# Concepts of Handling Cases In Different Places

Tags: oop, conceptual

I have a question about the naming of different concepts in object-oriented-programming.
Without trying to explain it through general means, let me illustrate it with two examples of the different concepts I'm speaking of.

---

I think a good way to illustrate this is the way how to handle damage immunity in games. Let's talk about fire that damages the entities that walk inside of it. Suppose, for example, there are spirits that are immune to fire, so they should not receive damage when walking there.

There are two ways to handle this kind of example situation (actually, three, but one isn't very 'useful'. I will state what it is at the end).

Firstly, the Entity class contains a boolean method/attribute called isImmuneToFire, and the method in the Fire class responsible for handling the process of damaging is checking on that. If this boolean is true, just return the method, if not, call the method damageBy(amount, source) in the entity class.

Secondly, the damage-handling method inside of Fire just calls damageBy(amount, source). Everything regarding immunity is just handled within the individual implementation of the method by the Entity classes. It's more like delegating the actual, repetitive work of immunity-handling to the responsible classes, while giving them more accurate control (for example, some entities could be immune to fire damage for 5 seconds after being hit once, or a player could wear fire immune armor, etc.)

I hope I could illustrate it good enough. Do these two different concepts have a name, or are they too 'marginal' to get one?

---

The mentioned third concept is to just brute-forcefully check the objects inside the damage-handling method (with `instanceof` in Java, for example) for their classes and thus deciding on whether damage should be dealt. This of course is a simple approach that just destroys any dynamical aspect and modularity. But if someone has a name for that, I'll accept it of course. Until then, I'll just continue on with calling it the Concept of `BFSJ Code`, short for `Brute-Force Static Jumble Code`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm allowed to tweak your question a little bit I would rather consider this under the light of Double Dispatching. Instead of having the source of damage checking whether it can damage an object,  or the object receiving the `damageBy(amount, source)` message having two switch among all possible values of `source`, you could get rid of the conditional logic in both places by having `Fire` send the message `fireDamage(amount)` instead. That way the source of damage will not have to check whether the object is immune to it or not, and the object will know what to do in its source-specific method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see your point, and by combining pre-defined methods in the parent class (for example `damageBy`) with voluntary-to-implement methods for the subclass (like `fireDamage`; the parent could just 'redirect' it to `damageBy` immediately, so only subclasses that have anything to do with this type of damage have to implement it themselves), it would be different, good approach to the problem (only problem being that it would need workarounds for other people creating mods/plugins that do not change pre-existing code).

Comment: However, this was not the complete intent of the question. I wanted to try and find names for the concepts I have in my mind, if they exist at all. But of course, being introduced to new concepts is interesting as well, just as being shown pros and cons of the concepts.

Comment: @Adowrath, I know. That's why I stated that may answer was implicitly tweaking your question. However, I still think that Double Dispatching is the closer well-known concept that responds to your problem.

Comment: Well, I guess I will mark it as an accepted answer if no one else answers with some names until Tuesday (don't rely on it though, I can be really forgetful). I anticipated it being a question of small 'success' anyway. ^^